# Listen one channel on multiple places in Go

Tags: go, goroutine

I know if once get the data from a channel that data won't receive from any other place that channel is waiting. However, if I want to design a program broadcast that channel has got data and It is ready to take out in different places without affecting other channels but in all places, I need to receive data in the same order, what will be the best design?

As a example:

```golang
func sender(c chan int){
c-> 5
}

func reciever1(c chan int){
 i:= <-c
...
}

func reciever2(c chan int){
 i:= <-c
...
}
```

Here when executing both `reciever1()` and `reciver2()` Both should get same result.

Comment: Make _two_ channels, one for each receiver and send the same value to both channels  / receivers.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create multiple channels and pass the same value to each of those channels.
Example

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main(){
    chann1 := make(chan int)
    chann2 := make(chan int)
    go func(){
        for {
            val :=<- chann1
            fmt.Println("GORoutine 1", val)
        }

    }()
    go func(){
        for {
            val :=<- chann2
            fmt.Println("GORoutine 2", val)
        }

    }()

    for i:=0;i<=10;i++{
        chann1 <- i
        chann2 <- i
    }


}
```